# How can I make a magic, subtle, universal translator?

Tags: ars-magica-5

My players are journeying to many different lands in mythic europe. Their magi, and covenant, speaks Latin and various dialects of Italian. However, the middle of eastern europe has many more languages then that.

In order to blend in and acquire information, the magi (or designated grog) needs to be able to understand the arbitrary language as well as being understood herself. What spells, invested into an item, will be necessary for the construction of a *subtle* universal translator?

Answer (score 4):

The ArM book gives us `Thoughts Within Babble`, a Base 5 (+1 Conc, +3 Hearing) = lv25 to *understand* all languages. InMe guidelines give us Base 15 for "Speak with any one human", so we can start by mixing those two togther for Level 35.

However, if we want to speak with multiple people, it's not quite the same as understanding all voice sounds. In the first case, the target is the sound. In the second, I think, the target is every person communicated with. In this case, I'd probably bump the Target from Individual to Group (+2), but drop the Range from Hearing to Voice (-1), since we only need to have people in voice range understand us.

So all in all, we've got `Undoing the Tower of Babel`, InMe40, Range: Voice, Duration: Concentration, Target: Group.

Comment: But how do I alter things such that the group *doesn't* think anything's wrong with understanding $OtherLanguage? Given that this needs to provide for bi-directional communication?

Comment: There isn't a specific description provided of the base "Speak with one human" effect, but I don't see why it would have to be an obvious effect - well, until you start talking to two people at once and each perceive it as a different language.

Comment: Regardless, if you do feel it necessary, a *Muto* requisite could be added to make the effect unnoticeable.